# Data structure that always keeps n-best elements

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, priority-queue

I need a data structure that always holds the `n` largest items inserted so far (in no particular order).

So, if `n` is 3, we could have the following session where I insert a few numbers and the content of the container changes:

```
[]  // now insert 1
[1] // now insert 0
[1,0] // now insert 4
[1,0,4] // now insert 3
[1,4,3] // now insert 0
[1,4,3] // now insert 3
[4,3,3]
```

You get the idea. What's the name of the data structure? What's the best way to implement this? Or is this in some library?

I am thinking to use a container that has a `priority_queue` for its elements (delegation), which uses the reverse comparison, so `pop` will remove the smallest element. So the `insert` function first checks if the new element to be inserted is greater than the smallest. If so, we throw that smallest out and push the new element.

(I have a `C++` implementation in mind, but the question is language-agnostic nevertheless.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The specific datastructure you want is probably the *implicit heap*.  The raw datastructure is just an array; for convenience, say that it is N=2^n elements in size, and that you want to maintain the largest N-1 elements.

The idea is to treat the array (call it A) as a complete binary tree of depth n:

- ignore A[0]; treat A[1] as the root node

  for each node A[k], the children are A[2*k] and A[2*k+1]

  nodes A[N/2..N-1] are the leaves

To maintain the tree as a "heap", you need to ensure that each node is smaller than (or equal to) its children.  This is called the "heap condition":

- A[k] <= A[2*k]

  A[k] <= A[2*k+1]

To use the heap to maintain the largest N elements:

- note that the root A[1] is the smallest element in the heap.

  compare each new element (x) to the root: if it is smaller (x<A[1]), reject it.

  otherwise, insert the new element into the heap, as follows:

  - remove the root (A[1], the smallest element) from the heap, and reject it

    replace it with the new element (A[1]:= x)

    now, restore the heap condition:

    - if x is less than or equal to both of its children, you're done

      otherwise, swap x with the smallest child

      repeat the test&swap at each new position until the heap condition is met

Basically, this will cause any replacement element to "filter up" the tree until it achieves its natural place.  This will take at most n=log2(N) steps, which is as good as you can get.  Also, the implicit form of the tree allows a very fast implementation; existing bounded-priority-queue libraries will most likely use an implicit heap.

Comment: As far as I can see this _is_ the priority solution proposed by the OP with the added optimization of folding the remove_smallest and insert_new actions.

Comment: This is most certainly **not** the most efficient you can get. See my answer for further information.

Answer (score 6):

In  Java you can use a SortedSet implemented e.g. by a TreeSet. After each insertion check if the set is too large, if yes remove the last element.

This is reasonably efficient, I have used it successfully for solving several Project Euler problems.

Comment: a TreeSet requires an ordering consistent with equals though, subject on wich the OP is not clear.

Answer (score 4):

A priority_queue is the closest thing in C++ with STL. You could wrap it in another class to create your own implementation that trims the size automatically.

Language-agnostically (although maybe not memory-fragmentation-safely):

1. Insert data
2. Sort
3. Delete everything after the nth element

std::priority_queue does step 2 for you.

Answer (score 2):

A *bounded priority queue*, I think... Java has something like this in its standard library. *EDIT*: it's called [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). I'm not sure if the C++ STL includes something similar.

Comment: It is not LinkedBlockingQueue, which blocks if size is exceeded instead of dropping smaller elements.

Comment: ah well, I thought there was one in the library, but it appears not.

Comment: There are some existing implementation for BoundedPriorityQueue, e.g. http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/util/BoundedPriorityQueue.html

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it possible to just take the first n elements from a sorted collection?

Comment: Yes, but that's not efficient in terms of space. I don't want to have to store all elements in this data structure. I'm be interested in a very small subset only. But for many cases that would be a fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Pyhton, use heapq. Create a small wrapper around it, something like this:

```
class TopN_Queue:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.max_sz = n
        self.data = []

    def add(self, x):
        if len(self.data) == self.max_sz:
            heapq.heappushpop(self.data, x)
        else:
            heapq.heappush(self.data, x)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can maintain a minimal head of size N
then you compare new item with the root item on each insertion
pop the root and insert the item if it's "greater" than the root
finally you end up with N largest items

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation in C++ 11.
Probably not the most optimal, but easy to use and concise.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    
    /// @brief Maintains a set of N elements with the best keys. (duplicate keys are allowed)
    template<class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key> >
    class KeepNBests{
    public:
        KeepNBests(size_t N=0):N(N), is_less(Compare()){}
    
        bool add(const Key& key, const T& t){
            // If there are enough elements,
            if(bests.size()>N // and the candidate key is worse than the worst stored key...
                && is_less(key, bests.cbegin()->first)){
                return false; // nothing to do
            }
            // else insert the new candidate
            bests.insert({key, t});
            // keeps max N elts
            while(bests.size()>N){
                bests.erase(bests.cbegin());
            }
            return true;
        }
        const std::multimap<Key, T, Compare>& get()const{
            return bests;
        }
    public:
        const size_t N;
    private:
        Compare is_less;
        std::multimap<Key, T, Compare> bests;
    };
    
    
    int main() {
        
      KeepNBests<double, std::string> best(3);
      best.add(0., "bad");
      best.add(0., "bad");
      best.add(300., "the best");
      best.add(10., "ok");
      best.add(-1., "bad");
      best.add(-7., "very bad");
      best.add(-1., "bad");
      best.add(100., "good");
      best.add(2., "bof");
      best.add(200., "the second");
    
      for(const auto& b : best.get()){
        std::cout << b.first << " " << b.second << std::endl;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Output :

```
 100 good
 200 the second
 300 the best
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a min-heap, also store a counter.

Whenever the counter is reached; extract-min.

You can do this in: O(1) insert, get-min and O(log log n) extract-min.`[1]` Alternatively you can do this with O(log n) insert and O(1) for the other mentioned operations.`[2]`

---

`[1]` M. Thorup, “Integer priority queues with decrease key in constant time and the single source shortest paths problem,” in Proceedings of the thirty-fifth annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing, New York, NY, USA, 2003, pp. 149–158.

`[2]` G. S. Brodal, G. Lagogiannis, C. Makris, A. Tsakalidis, and K. Tsichlas, “Optimal finger search trees in the pointer machine,” J. Comput. Syst. Sci., vol. 67, no. 2, pp. 381–418, Sep. 2003.

Comment: What is the counter counting? When is it reached?

Comment: Counter keeps track of how many items are currently in the data-structure. The Finger Tree is the best solution here (asymptotically speaking). Just remove-max until the counter is within the specified threshold.