# Continuous monitoring and updating of popularity of items

Tags: algorithm, e-commerce, recommendation-engine

Suppose we have `1000` items and a place to show any ten of these items at a time, to the visiting user. We can capture click rate and items which are shown together.

1. How can we optimally get the most popular items (say `10`) out of these?
2. How can we continually update popularity and show the optimal `10` items?

Edit: I'm looking for the different approaches instead of implementations.

Comment: Maintain a `max heap`. It should work.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: Which operation happens more frequently?  The reorder or the view-top-10?  If the view operation dominates you want to maintain items in a sorted order (e.g. BST).  If the reorder dominates, you may be willing to incur some more overhead on the top-10 operation in exchange for a cheaper reorder operation (look into different max-heap implementations).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to squeeze this down, there is a dumb/simple approach for your case (show top 1%).

This optimization can happen because on average, only 1 out of 100 popularity changes will knock out one of the top 1%.  *(Assumes a random distribution of updates.  Of course with a more typical power-law distribution, this could happen much more frequently.)*

1. **Sort the entire initial collection,**

   - Store only the top 10 in any sorted data structure (e.g. BST)
   - Store the popularity score of #10 (e.g. `minVisiblePopularity`)
2. **then with each subsequent popularity change in the collection, compare with `minVisiblePopularity`.**

   - If the new popularity falls above the `minVisiblePopularity`, update the top-10 structure and `minVisiblePopularity` accordingly.
   - *(Or if the old popularity was greater, but new popularity is less - e.g. former top 10 item getting knocked out)*.

*This adds a minimal storage requirement of an extremely small binary search tree (10 items) and a primitive variable.  The tree then only requires updating when a popularity change knocks out one of the previous top-10.*

Comment: Just saw an earlier answer along these lines for [What is the best data structure for keeping the top n elements in sort order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969909/what-is-the-best-data-structure-for-keeping-the-top-n-elements-in-sort-order#14986415) (with discussion)

Answer (score 0):

**Self implemented:**

To maintain ordered array by popularity and a hash table that contain reference to corresponding item in the popularity binary tree.
So, last 10 would the most popular items, access to them will be O(M) where M is count of items to show.

To maintain ordered array:

It can be maintained using self-balancing binary tree with log(N) complexity where N is total count of elements

http://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-2/

**As a practical option:**

database can be used to store items and B-tree index can be added to popularity column; DBMS will have required optimizations here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index