# How can I improve the speed and memory usage of calculating the size of the N largest files?

Tags: powershell, performance, get-childitem, memory-efficient, directory-listing

I am getting the total number of bytes of the 32 largest files in the folder:

```
$big32 = Get-ChildItem c:\\temp -recurse |
    Sort-Object length -descending |
    select-object -first 32 |
    measure-object -property length –sum

$big32.sum /1gb
```

However, it's working very slowly.  We have about 10 TB of data in 1.4 million files.

Comment: 10TB of data, but how many files?

Comment: Pass `-File` to `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate only files.  Depending on the composition of ``c:\temp\`` (file count vs. directory count), that might yield a performance increase.  Also, how slow is "very slowly"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  1.4million files

Comment: Well yeah, sorting 1.4 million files by length is going to take a while. This is true even on the lowest level (that is, if you used the Windows APIs directly). `[IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles` can be used for fire-hose enumerating that will give the files in arbitrary order, but then the sort still needs to happen. That said, using `EnumerateFiles` as a base here is probably still considerably faster than `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: You can also use robocopy for this. See [Powershell calling Robocopy to get top32 largest files total size not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705878/powershell-calling-robocopy-to-get-top32-largest-files-total-size-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

I can think of some improvements, especially to memory usage but following should be considerable faster than `Get-ChildItem`

```
[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('c:\temp', '*.*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) | 
    Foreach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            filename = $_
            length = [System.IO.FileInfo]::New($_).Length
        }
    } | 
    Sort-Object length -Descending | 
    Select-Object -First 32
```

**Edit**

I would look at trying to implement an [implit heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564210/52598) to reduce memory usage without hurting performance (possibly even improves it... to be tested)

**Edit 2**

If the filenames are not required, the easiest gain on memory is to not include them in the results.

```
[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('c:\temp', '*.*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) | 
    Foreach-Object {
        [System.IO.FileInfo]::New($_).Length
    } | 
    Sort-Object length -Descending | 
    Select-Object -First 32
```

Answer (score 3):

The following implements improvements by only using PowerShell cmdlets. Using `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles()` as a basis as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70244520/7571258) might give another performance improvement but you should do your own measurements to compare.

```
(Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Recurse -File).ForEach('Length') | 
    Sort-Object -Descending -Top 32 | 
    Measure-Object -Sum
```

This should reduce memory consumption considerably as it only sorts an array of numbers instead of an array of `FileInfo` objects. Maybe it's also somewhat faster due to better caching (an array of numbers is stored in a contiguous, cache-friendly block of memory, whereas an array of objects only stores the references in a contiguous way, but the objects themselfs can be scattered all around in memory).

Note the use of `.ForEach('Length')` instead of just `.Length` because of [member enumeration ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67547356/7571258).

By using `Sort-Object` parameter `-Top` we can get rid of the `Select-Object` cmdlet, further reducing pipeline overhead.

Comment: Thanks, first time I heard of member enumeration.  Drawback is that you lose the filenames but that is not a requirement by OP. I'll amend my answer to just return the Length so OP can do a proper comparison of speed/memory.

Comment: Just tried a combination of EnumerateFiles and member enumeration.  For the tests I've done, that is the fastest consistantly. Feel free to add that to you answer and I'll delete mine.
`([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('c:\temp', '*.*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)).ForEach({[System.IO.FileInfo]::New($_).Length}) | Sort-Object -Descending -Top 32 | Measure-Object -Sum`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I'd like to keep my answer as a "pure PowerShell way" for cases when readability counts more than performance. You came up with `EnumerateFiles`, so any further improvement to it belongs to your answer as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you're going to use `Get-ChildItem` then you should pass the `-File` switch parameter so that `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instances never enter the pipeline.

Secondly, you're not passing the `-Force` switch parameter to `Get-ChildItem`, so any hidden files in that directory structure won't be retrieved.

Thirdly, note that your code is retrieving the 32 *largest files*, not the files with the 32 *largest lengths*.  That is, if files 31, 32, and 33 are all the same length, then file 33 will be arbitrarily excluded from the final count.  If that distinction is important to you you could rewrite your code like this...

```
$filesByLength = Get-ChildItem -File -Force -Recurse -Path 'C:\Temp\' |
    Group-Object -AsHashTable -Property Length
$big32 = $filesByLength.Keys |
    Sort-Object -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 32 |
    ForEach-Object -Process { $filesByLength[$_] } |
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
```

`$filesByLength` is a `[Hashtable]` that maps from a length to the file(s) with that length.  The `Keys` property contains all of the unique lengths of all of the retrieved files, so we get the 32 largest keys/lengths and use each one to send all the files of that length down the pipeline.

Most importantly, sorting the retrieved files to find the largest ones is problematic for several reasons:

- Sorting cannot start until all of the input data is available, meaning at that point in time all 1.4 million `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances will be present in memory.

  - I'm not sure how `Sort-Object` buffers the incoming pipeline data, but I imagine it would be some kind of list that doubles in size every time it needs more capacity, leading to further garbage in memory to be cleaned up.
- Each of the 1.4 million `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances will be accessed a second time to get their `Length` property, all the while whatever sorting manipulations (depending on what algorithm `Sort-Object` uses) are occurring, too.

Since we only care about a mere 32 largest files/lengths out of 1.4 million files, what if we only kept track of those 32 instead of all 1.4 million?  Consider if we only wanted to find the single largest file...

```
$largestFileLength = 0
$largestFile = $null

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -File -Force -Recurse -Path 'C:\Temp\')
{
    # Track the largest length in a separate variable to avoid two comparisons...
    #     if ($largestFile -eq $null -or $file.Length -gt $largestFile.Length)
    if ($file.Length -gt $largestFileLength)
    {
        $largestFileLength = $file.Length
        $largestFile = $file
    }
}

Write-Host -Message "The largest file is named ""$($largestFile.Name)"" and has length $largestFileLength."
```

As opposed to `Get-ChildItem ... | Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending | Select-Object -First 1`, this has the advantage of only one `[FileInfo]` object being "in-flight" at a time and the complete set of `[System.IO.FileInfo]`s being enumerated only once.  Now all we need to do is to take the same approach but expanded from 1 file/length "slot" to 32...

```
$basePath = 'C:\Temp\'
$lengthsToKeep = 32
$includeZeroLengthFiles = $false

$listType = 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.FileInfo]'
# A SortedDictionary[,] could be used instead to avoid having to fully enumerate the Keys
# property to find the new minimum length, but add/remove/retrieve performance is worse
$dictionaryType = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.Int64, $listType]"

# Create a dictionary pre-sized to the maximum number of lengths to keep
$filesByLength = New-Object -TypeName $dictionaryType -ArgumentList $lengthsToKeep

# Cache the minimum length currently being kept
$minimumKeptLength = -1L

Get-ChildItem -File -Force -Recurse -Path $basePath |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        if ($_.Length -gt 0 -or $includeZeroLengthFiles)
        {
            $list = $null
            if ($filesByLength.TryGetValue($_.Length, [ref] $list))
            {
                # The current file's length is already being kept
                # Add the current file to the existing list for this length
                $list.Add($_)
            }
            else
            {
                # The current file's length is not being kept

                if ($filesByLength.Count -lt $lengthsToKeep)
                {
                    # There are still available slots to keep more lengths

                    $list = New-Object -TypeName $listType

                    # The current file's length will occupy an empty slot of kept lengths
                }
                elseif ($_.Length -gt $minimumKeptLength)
                {
                    # There are no available slots to keep more lengths
                    # The current file's length is large enough to keep

                    # Get the list for the minimum length
                    $list = $filesByLength[$minimumKeptLength]

                    # Remove the minimum length to make room for the current length
                    $filesByLength.Remove($minimumKeptLength) |
                        Out-Null

                    # Reuse the list for the now-removed minimum length instead of allocating a new one
                    $list.Clear()

                    # The current file's length will occupy the newly-vacated slot of kept lengths
                }
                else
                {
                    # There are no available slots to keep more lengths
                    # The current file's length is too small to keep
                    return
                }
                $list.Add($_)

                $filesByLength.Add($_.Length, $list)
                $minimumKeptLength = ($filesByLength.Keys | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
            }
        }
    }

# Unwrap the files in each by-length list
foreach ($list in $filesByLength.Values)
{
    foreach ($file in $list)
    {
        $file
    }
}
```

I went with the approach, described above, of retrieving the files with the 32 largest lengths.  A [`[Dictionary[Int64, List[FileInfo]]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) is used to track those 32 largest lengths and the corresponding files with that length.  For each input file, we first check if its length is among the largest so far and, if so, add the file to the existing [`List[FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) for that length.  Otherwise, if there's still room in the dictionary we can unconditionally add the input file and its length, or if the input file is at least bigger than the smallest tracked length we can remove that smallest length and add in its place the input file and its length.  Once there are no more input files we output all of the `[FileInfo]` objects from all of the `[List[FileInfo]]`s in the `[Dictionary[Int64, [List[FileInfo]]]]`.

I ran this simple benchmarking template...

```
1..5 |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        [GC]::Collect()

        return Measure-Command -Expression {
            # Code to test
        }
    } | Measure-Object -Property 'TotalSeconds' -Minimum -Maximum -Average
```

...on PowerShell 7.2 against my `$Env:WinDir` directory (325,000 files) with these results:

| `# Code to test` | Minimum | Maximum | Average | Memory usage* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `Get-ChildItem -File -Force -Recurse -Path $Env:WinDir` | 69.7240896 | 79.727841 | 72.81731518 | +260 MB |
| Get `$Env:WinDir` files with 32 largest lengths using `-AsHashtable`, `Sort-Object` | 82.7488729 | 83.5245153 | 83.04068032 | +1 GB |
| Get `$Env:WinDir` files with 32 largest lengths using dictionary of by-length lists | 81.6003697 | 82.7035483 | 82.15654538 | +235 MB |

** As observed in the `Task Manager` → `Details` tab → `Memory (active private working set)` column*

I'm a little disappointed that my solution is only about 1% faster than the code using the `Keys` of a `[Hashtable]`, but perhaps grouping the files using a compiled cmdlet vs. not grouping or sorting them but with more (interpreted) PowerShell code is a wash.  Still, the difference in memory usage is significant, though I can't explain why the `Get-ChildItem` call to simply enumerate all files ended up using a bit more.

Comment: Nice. I feel like a combination of the current three answers is the way to go. Using a `Dictionary`, `EnumerateFiles` and `member enumeration` would performance and memory wise beat all solutions.

Comment: Nice algorithmic exploration of the problem. Regarding benchmarking I don't think `[GC]::Collect()` is sufficient. The [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048708/7571258) seems to be this sequence: `[GC]::Collect(); [GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers(); [GC]::Collect()`. I'd rather start a new PowerShell process for each run to be on the safe side.